# «Все(,) кому не лень»

Tags: пунктуация, фразеология, запятые

**Все(,) кому не лень** — нужна ли тут запятая? Или это устойчивый оборот?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если верить Розенталю, нужна.

//Запятой отделяются также неполные или близкие к неполным придаточные предложения, например: Он не понял, в чем дело; Рад помочь, чем смогу; Запомнил, чему учили; Люди знают, что делают; Сделайте, что нужно; Могу предоставить все, что угодно; Он понимает, что к чему; Садитесь, где свободно; **Ругали все, кому не лень**; Встретимся, знаете где; Болтал, не знаю что. Но: Делай что хочешь и т. п.//

Ответ справочной службы "РУССКИЕ СЛОВАРИ": "Нам сложно дать четкую рекомендацию по этому поводу. С одной стороны, данное выражение фразеологично, поэтому его следовало бы писать без запятой после *все*; с другой стороны, в Толковом словаре русского языка С. И. Ожегова и Н. Ю. Шведовой этот оборот приводится с запятой. Предполагаем, что в данном случае допустимо вариативное написание."

Answer (score 0):

В таких оборотах не нужна запятая.

Answer (score -1):

Не нужна! Конечно же, это — фразеологизм.

Answer (score -1):

Вот, всё вы, филологи, усложняете на ровном месте! Пунктуация придумана, чтобы точнее передавать смысл речи и ИНТОНАЦИЮ её. Если автор хочет выделить часть фразеологизма паузами, т.е. интонационно, то он имеет полное моральное, логическое и грамматическое право ставить запятые. Если не хочет выделять, то при устоявшемся выражении, как в данном случае, имеет право не ставить запятых. Остальное - дело вкуса и выдумки известных людей (ни в коем разе не хочу никого из них обидеть!) типа Розенталя, Ожегова и Ушаковой.

Comment: А кто такая Ушакова? Неужели Дмитрий Николаевич?

Comment: Насчет грамматического права не согласен, с логическим правом не знаком, моральное здесь не обсуждается. Ставлю минус.